Docker does not see copied files and does not execute it
I wrote a Dockerfile to make an image of my project:
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
ADD go.mod .
COPY . .
RUN go build -o bot .

FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/bot /app/bot
COPY migration migration
COPY migrate.sh .
RUN chmod +x migrate.sh
CMD ["./bot"]

I need to copy migration directory and migrate.sh script to make migrations.
Then I wrote a docker-compose file:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
    networks:
      - bot-reminder
  bot:
    image: my_image
    container_name: bot
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      TOKEN: ${TOKEN}
      TIMEOUT: ${TIMEOUT}
      MAX_MSG_SIZE: ${MAX_MSG_SIZE}
      CHANNEL_ID: ${CHANNEL_ID}
      LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL}
    networks:
      - bot-reminder
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: ["./migrate.sh", "up"]
networks:
  bot-reminder:

But when I run docker compose up -d, the bot container gives an error:
exec ./migrate.sh: no such file or directory
I run a command docker export bot > files.tar. I saw all necessary files inside of files.tar.
But why then container gives an error? Why it does not execute it?
I tried to write command ./migrate.sh up in different ways: app/migrate.sh, ./app/migrate.sh, /app/migrate.sh but it didn't work.
I also added command ls and it printed all necessary files.

What is the first line of migrate.sh?  If it's #!/bin/bash, that shell doesn't exist in Alpine Linux; is you're on a Windows host an it's #!/bin/sh\r ending with a newline character, that would also cause this problem.

(Also remember that a Compose command: override runs instead of the image's CMD.  You may need to docker-compose run the migration script, or use an entrypoint wrapper script to run migrations before running the main container command.)

@DavidMaze yes, the first line is #!/bin/bash

You don't say what the script actually does, but if it only uses POSIX shell features then you can probably change the shebang line to #!/bin/sh without changing anything else, and then it will work with Alpine as well.

Can you check your .dockerignore file?
and also add build you container everytime you run docker compose
 bot:
    image: my_image
    container_name: bot
    build:
      context: .


I didn't do any .dockerignore file. So I looked for it and found in the directory welcome-to-docker. It consists of only one line: node_modules

I added a build: context: . lines but it didn't help, I got the same error: exec ./migrate.sh: no such file or directory

If you project publicly available on github or similar sites? If yes share the link

yes, here it is. current brunch: feature/deploy-workflow. https://github.com/Pizhlo/bot-reminder-go-telegram/tree/feature/deploy-workflow

alright, check github
